# Install GDB remotely onto a Mac through SSH?

Tags: macos, ssh, certificate, keychain, gdb

I've built the binaries for GDB on the Mac, but now I need to codesign it, and every tutorial tells me to open up the Keychain GUI to achieve this. I don't have any access to the actual computer, I can only interface with it through an ssh terminal.

Comment: Can you tunnel VNC or other remote desktop through ssh?

Comment: You can enable Screen Sharing on the remote Mac via SSH, then create a reverse SSH Tunnel for the VNC tcp port, and connect with it using a local VNC client. To enable screen sharing via SSH follow this tutorial: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-screen-sharing-on-macs-via-terminal/